# Nested Logic in Persisted Columns Formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, nested, persisted-column

I'm new to and having trouble with Formulae Syntax in Persisted Columns.

A - I need *case when (CustomerAccountID IS NULL and MissCustNameMatched=0) OR errLicensingProgMissing=1 OR errLicensingSubMissing=1 then (1) else (0) end*

This won't validate correctly.

B - Or can I do it somehow like this *

case

- when [MissCustName] IS true then
- - when [CustomerAccountName] IS NULL then
- - - (1)
- - else
- - - (0)
- - end
- else
- - (0)
- end*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two cases don't match on column names but following persisted field declaration shows how it could be done using a `CASE` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test (
  CustomerAccountID INTEGER
  , MissCustNameMatched INTEGER
  , errLicensingProgMissing INTEGER
  , errLicensingSubMissing INTEGER
  , persistedField AS 
      CASE MissCustNameMatched WHEN 1 
      THEN 
        CASE CustomerAccountID WHEN 1 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END 
      ELSE 0 
      END PERSISTED
)
```